# Applying margins programmatically in a Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I cannot get margins to work correctly when using a `ConstraintSet`

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    // START WORKS
    //constraintSet.connect(R.id.text, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 50);
    // LEFT DOES NOT
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.text, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 50);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.text, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 50);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.text, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 50);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.text, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 50);

    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

There's a small sample app there if anyone wants to reproduce: https://github.com/martinbonnin/TestConstraintLayout/tree/master

Anyone knows what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. What is your expected result.

But...
You are using END and LEFT which is a little strange.
normally you would use START&END or LEFT&RIGHT